# jquery ui accordion in new tab not working

Tags: jquery, dynamic, user-interface, tabs, accordion

How do I get a JQuery UI accordion to work in a dynamically added tab?
I want it so that every time a new tab is created, it is created with a new accordion object in it.
Here is an example of code using basic tab examples off of the Jquery UI site, slightly modified to include a  with an accordion with 2 sections in it.

As of right now the tabs work correctly, but inside the new tabs the accordion contents is shown as regular HTML, not as an accordion jquery object.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
#dialog label, #dialog input { display:block; }
#dialog label { margin-top: 0.5em; }
#dialog input, #dialog textarea { width: 95%; }
#tabs { margin-top: 1em; }
#tabs li .ui-icon-close { float: left; margin: 0.4em 0.2em 0 0; cursor: pointer; }
#add_tab { cursor: pointer; }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "#accordion" ).accordion();

   var tabTitle = $( "#tab_title" ),
        tabContent = $( "#tab_content" ),
        tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
        tabCounter = 2;

    var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    // modal dialog init: custom buttons and a "close" callback reseting the form inside
    var dialog = $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Add: function() {
                addTab();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            form[ 0 ].reset();
        }
    });

    // addTab form: calls addTab function on submit and closes the dialog
    var form = dialog.find( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        addTab();
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
    function addTab() {
        var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
            id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
            li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
            tabContentHtml = tabContent.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";

        tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
        tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><div id='accordion'><h3>header1</h3><div><p>PARAGRAPH1</p></div><h3>header2</h3><div><p>PARA2</p></div></div></div>" );
        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
        tabCounter++;
    }

    // addTab button: just opens the dialog
    $( "#add_tab" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            dialog.dialog( "open" );
        });

    // close icon: removing the tab on click
    $( "#tabs span.ui-icon-close" ).live( "click", function() {
        var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
        $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Tab data">
    <form>
        <fieldset class="ui-helper-reset">
            <label for="tab_title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="tab_title" id="tab_title" value="" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <label for="tab_content">Content</label>
            <textarea name="tab_content" id="tab_content" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<button id="add_tab">Add Tab</button>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close">Remove Tab</span></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call .accordion() on the newly created element again after the new tab is appended to the DOM.

Comment: This is the key and just in case anyone tries to add the accordion code using AJAX, you then need to initiate the accordion widget after the AJAX using something like AJAX.then.

Answer (score 0):

just replace this line -

```
tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><div id='accordion'>"+tabContentHtml+"</div>" );
```

see here - http://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/nLqmN/